# display email inbox?

Tags: iphone, ipad, email

is there an option that I could retrieve from my app the latest 10 email subjects from my ipad email inbox.

I would like to display the user his last 10 subjects in my new app.

Any Ideas if this is possible and how?

best
chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not. Apple doesn't allow access to most user data that's handled by the built-in native software, and even then generally not without the user explicitly giving the app access (such as in an address book picker).

Comment: thanks... I have no problem if the user have explicit to allow that, would it be than possible and how?

Comment: No, sorry, this one's not even possible with user allowance. It's just not in the API. Sorry for for being clearer.